# In spring data cassandra updating udf field via update.query results in error

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to update cassandra nested field (udt) using spring data query API:

```
cql.update(Query.query(
            Criteria.where(Attachment.Key.MESSAGE_ID).is(5),
            Criteria.where(Attachment.Key.ATTACHMENT_ID).is(6)
    ), Update.update(Attachment.DATA + '.' + Attachment.AttachmentData.DT_STATUS, Attachment.AttachmentData.builder()
            .status("Hello5")
            .build()
    ), Attachment.class);
```

And that results in error:

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: Query; CQL [UPDATE attachment SET status=? WHERE message_id=? AND attachment_id=?]; Undefined column name status in table geps.attachment; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name status in table geps.attachment
```

I tried to use quotes for field name without significant success. It reported

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: Query; CQL [UPDATE attachment SET "data.status"=? WHERE message_id=? AND attachment_id=?]; Undefined column name "data.status" in table geps.attachment; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name "data.status" in table geps.attachment
```

So is it rather possible?

I know as a workaround I can use datastax driver directly for that:

```
        cql.getCqlOperations().execute("UPDATE attachment SET data.status='Hello2' WHERE message_id=5 and attachment_id=6");
    Attachment msg2 = cql.selectOneById(key, Attachment.class);
    assertThat(msg2.getData().getStatus(), is("Hello2"));
```

Or even prepared statement

```
    cql.getCqlOperations().execute((SessionCallback<Object>) s -> {
        PreparedStatement prepared = s.prepare("UPDATE attachment SET data.status=:status WHERE message_id=:messageId and attachment_id=:attachmentId");
        BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind()
                .setString("status", "Hello3")
                .setLong("messageId", 5)
                .setLong("attachmentId", 6);
        ResultSet result = s.execute(bound);
        result.forEach(r -> log.info("Result: {}", r));
        return result;
    });
```

But spring data update API is beautiful.

I created small [code snippet](https://github.com/mpashka/home-incubator/blob/master/java-tests/spring/spring-data/spring-data-cassandra/src/test/java/org/mpashka/spring/data/cassandra/UpdateNestedAttachmentTest.java#L108-L114) to test it. It requires running local cassandra.